# Multiple selector with the same pseudo-class

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Is there a neater way to have one pseudo-class for multiple selector?

For example:

```
th:first-of-type, td:first-of-type {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in CSS, but if you were using a preprocessor like Sass you could organize it a bit like this. (Note that the CSS produced will still compile to your original example.)

```
th,
td {
  &:first-of-type {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```